# Casting UInt16 to Int16 will occur a program crash

Tags: swift

How do i avoid a program crash, when I cast a UInt16(value over 32767) to Int16.

In Object-C is easy and safe:

```
uint16_t a = 32888
int16_t  b = (int16_t)a
```

But I don't have any idea in Swift.

Comment: Obviously you can check the range before you make the invalid cast.

Comment: Why use a signed 16 bit integer for a value that might be over? Just use a bigger data type...

Comment: Because I have to open a file that format UInt16 is defined

Comment: I hope that the referenced thread answers your question. In your case it would be: `let a : UInt16 = 32888 ; let b = Int16(bitPattern: a)`.

Comment: Thanks Martin, You provide a convenient way for me

Comment: @MartinR This is the right answer, you should make it a formal answer that can be accepted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the following function:

```
func toInt(unsigned: UInt) -> Int {

    let signed = (unsigned <= UInt(Int.max)) ?
        Int(unsigned) :
        Int(unsigned - UInt(Int.max) - 1) + Int.min

    return signed
}
```

Comment: thanks! It works very well.

Comment: `numericCast(...)` is what you're looking for. It's a set of generic functions that converts from and to different number types. It picks the correct implementation based on the types of its argument and the return type.